# Passing Data from DataGrid to Click Function of Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a little rusty with WPF, and don't think I have all the basics figured out. I'm working with a DataGrid, and I have my values inserted, and I've created a column template that adds a button to each row of the data grid. What I want to do is call a method on the class of object in the data grid.

For Example. Say I have a data grid defined as this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="550" Name="WidgetGrid" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click" >Issue New Widget</Button>
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in the CS, I have the grid data initialized with the `ItemsSource` property of the data grid.

The Objects being Sent to `ItemsSource` have a method called `increment`, and I want to call it for the object on the row for which the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create command of type ICommand for ItemsSource object, then use Button `<Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}"</Button>`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, so I should setup a property on the underlying data type of `ICommand` set it to do my dirty work, and simply bind the command on the button. Okay, I think that makes some sense. Mind sending me a PM to continue discussing?

Comment: @Chris Rutherford Did I undestand right, you have a ViewModel for item, and you use ObservableCollection<ViewModel> for ItemsSource? In this case, it is more convenient handle the command in viewmodel, but I don't know do you use any framework which realize the ICommand pattern? Button Click uses only for code behind, if you will do common action not specific for concrete items.

Comment: Sorry I got it working another way. I was doing it differently. Used to nodejs, and doing something different in c#.... All food